# let $α, β, γ, δ$ be endomorphisms such that $α − β$ and $α + β$ are automorphisms. Show that exist $ϕ$, $ψ$ such that $ϕα + ψβ = γ$, $ψα + ϕβ = δ$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I need some help with this problem:

Let $F$ be a field of characteristic other than 2. Let $V$
be a vector space over $F$ and let $α, β, γ, δ$ be endomorphisms of $V$
satisfying the condition that $α − β$ and $α + β$ are automorphisms of
$V$. Show that there exist endomorphisms $ϕ$ and $ψ$ of $V$ satisfying
$ϕα + ψβ = γ$ and $ψα + ϕβ = δ$.

Thanks.

This is an exercise from the book: The Linear Algebra a Beginning Graduate Student Should Know by Golan.

Comment: You really need to have a solution book for all these exercises of Golan's book !

Comment: There is not such a thing, That's why I ask for help with the problems I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me reformulate your question:

> Let $R$ be a ring, and $a,b,c,d\in R$ with $a-b,a+b$ invertible. Show that there exist $u,v\in R$ such that $ua+vb=c$ and $va+ub=d$.

Did you find this easier to handle? (If not, see below for a hint.)

> **Hint.** Add and subtract the last two equations.

Comment: Thanks, I remembered that I did this same problem with rings